After deleting old files in /root, su no longer works (it hangs after password is typed)
I wanted to delete old files in a folder with the following command:
find . -type f -ctime +1000 -print0|xargs -0 rm

Unfortunately I ran it in /root instead of in the folder I wanted (if you want to know: I first tried as my regular user, noticed I didn't have permissions because I don't own the files, then did su - and ran the command again ), so I deleted all old files under /root.
Now, when I do su - (or su, or su -s bash; I normally use Zsh), it asks me for the root password as usual, and then just sits there until I control-C:
$ su -
Password: █ ← this is the cursor hanging there after I typed the root password and pressed enter

No file gets written in /var/log/.
System is Debian, sudo is not installed. Logging directly as root from the console works fine.
ps xauf contains the following lines when it's hanging there:
(my username) 2991479  0.0  0.1  12992  6672 pts/0    Ss   09:11   0:00          \_ -zsh
root          2992735  0.0  0.0   9644  3960 pts/0    S+   09:42   0:00              \_ su -

so, no child process running yet.
The same happens if I type the wrong password, it still just hangs. It also happens when I try to switch to a user other than root. However when I'm root, su to a user works fine. Something to do with checking a password?
All this is apparently caused by some missing file in /root, but which one could that be?

Maybe that's some shell rc file; try copying the files from /etc/skel that are missing in /root (don't forget to chown them). (This directory is copied into new users home directory on creation.) Also try to go other way: delete (or, rather, move somewhere) all the remaining files, and try to log in again; maybe it's "some still existing file references some deleted"; by deleting still existing file you may resolve the problem.

Hum so I copied .bashrc and bash_logout. I did not copy .profile because there already was one. And then it worked! And then I deleted those two files again. And it still works! What is this I don't even. I suppose some other temporarily prevented su from working and it fixed itself? I'll probably never know what happened. Thank you @NikitaKipriyanov for maybe giving me the key to solve this issue!
